# is there any way to use letter spacing in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, .net-core-3.1

I am developing WPF Application in which I want to Format my Text resides in TextBlock Control.

I want to implement Letter Spacing in WPF.

Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/789c3e1b-e3ae-476f-b37f-d93ef6d0cb7b/character-spacing-in-textblocktextelement?forum=wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried Glyphs and FontStretch and couldn't easily get the result I was looking for. I was able to come up with an approach that works for my purposes. Maybe it will work for others, as well.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeString}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                           Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I can apply this on the single line content but can't do it for a Multiline (paragraph) please share if you have any knowledge on it.